# Why didn't the ninjas in Kumogakure adopt Chidori?

Tags: naruto, boruto

[Chidori](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Chidori) was invented by Kakashi Hatake and the only users of Chidori apart from Kakashi are Sasuke and Sarada. Now, [Lightning release technique](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Lightning_Release) are primarily used by ninjas in [Kumogakure](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Kumogakure) and they are the best in the business when it comes to lightning related Ninjutsu. So, why didn't they adopt Chidori? Is it so inefficient that they can not be bothered to use it or is it that they have other jutsu in their belt so that they don't require Chidori or is it that they have a strict rule of not using jutsus invented from a different region?

Come to think of it, if they are that proficient in lightning release technique, they could have invented Chidori a long time ago. How is that Kakashi was the one to invent it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Chidori was invented by Kakashi Hatake and the only users of Chidori apart from Kakashi are Sasuke and Sarada.

Something that these three ninjas have in common is that they possess a Sharingan, which is a requirement to use this technique to its fullest potential.

> The speed at which the Chidori is performed, despite being one of its greatest assets, also represents one of its biggest drawbacks: users move at their target so fast that its causes a tunnel vision-like effect for them. Because they charge in a straight line it is easy for opponents to attack them, and because of the tunnel vision it is difficult for the user to see these attacks, much less react to them. **For this reason, most ninja cannot use the Chidori safely. However, a user of the Sharingan can overcome these drawbacks due to its heightened visual perception preventing the tunnel vision from occurring and its predictive capabilities making it easier for the user to avoid counterattacks.**

[Wiki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Chidori#Overview)

The average Kumo ninja doesn't have a Sharingan, which makes this technique unsuitable to them. That is not to say that they don't possess similar jutsus.

For instance, the Third Raikage's [Hell Stab](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Hell_Stab) technique bears similarities to the Chidori and Raikiri. Sasuke's technique, the [Sword of Kusanagi: Chidori Katana](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Sword_of_Kusanagi:_Chidori_Katana), where he channels the Chidori through his sword, closely resembles Killer B's [Supervibrato Lightning Release Swords](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Supervibrato_Lightning_Release_Swords). [Darui](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Darui?so=search#Kenjutsu) is also able to channel his lightning chakra through his sword.